# CIFAR-10 can't get above 10% Accuracy with MobileNet, VGG16 and ResNet on Keras

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train the most popular Models (mobileNet, VGG16, ResNet...) with the CIFAR10-dataset but the accuracy can't get above 9,9%. I want to do that with the completely model (include_top=True) and without the weights from imagenet.

I have tried increasing/decreasing dropout and learning rate and I changed the optimizers but I become always the same accuracy.

with weights='imagenet' and include_top=False I achieve an accuracy of over 90% but I want to train the model without those parameters.

Is there any solution to solve this? It is possible, that the layers of those Models are not set to be trainable?

```
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
                                    rotation_range=2, 
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    zoom_range=.1 )
val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
                                    rotation_range=2, 
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    zoom_range=.1)

train_generator.fit(x_train)
val_generator.fit(x_val)

base_model_1 = MobileNet(include_top=True,weights=None,input_shape=(32,32,3),classes=y_train.shape[1])

batch_size= 100
epochs=50

learn_rate=.001

sgd=SGD(lr=learn_rate,momentum=.9,nesterov=False)
adam=Adam(lr=learn_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)

model_1.compile(optimizer=adam,loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.fit_generator(train_generator.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=batch_size),
                      epochs=epochs,
                      steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]//batch_size,
                      validation_data=val_generator.flow(x_val,y_val,batch_size=batch_size),validation_steps=250,
                      verbose=1)
```

Results of MobileNet:

```
    Epoch 1/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 50ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1021
Epoch 2/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1030
Epoch 3/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1016
Epoch 4/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1014
Epoch 5/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1040
Epoch 6/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1009
Epoch 7/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1035
Epoch 8/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1013
Epoch 9/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1029
Epoch 10/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1023
Epoch 11/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1017
Epoch 12/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1020
Epoch 13/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1020
Epoch 14/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1033
Epoch 15/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1011
Epoch 16/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1016
Epoch 17/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1024
Epoch 18/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1024
Epoch 19/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1041
Epoch 20/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1010
Epoch 21/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1022
Epoch 22/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1014
Epoch 23/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1035
Epoch 24/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1032
Epoch 25/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 26/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1018
Epoch 27/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1022
Epoch 28/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1031
Epoch 29/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1022
Epoch 30/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1015
Epoch 31/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1028
Epoch 32/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1015
Epoch 33/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1030
Epoch 34/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1003
Epoch 35/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1044
Epoch 36/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 37/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1022
Epoch 38/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1021
Epoch 39/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1028
Epoch 40/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 41/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1035
Epoch 42/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1009
Epoch 43/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1034
Epoch 44/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1024
Epoch 45/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1016
Epoch 46/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1028
Epoch 47/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1016
Epoch 48/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1033
Epoch 49/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1018
Epoch 50/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1023

<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fa30b188e48>
```

Comment: try rescaling your inputs (between 0 and 1)

Comment: @SajanGohil thanks for your answer but I don't know what do you exactly mean, how can I do that?

Comment: Your loss is `NaN` : your model is not learning anything. So your accuracy is the same as random choice. You first need to fix your loss.

Comment: add rescale parameter in your generators or divide your inputs by 255 beforehand. I am assuming they are in uint8 format (0-255 values)

Comment: Hi @SajanGohil could you take a look here? https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/27687/visualisation-for-mobilenet-feature-extraction